# Own layouts in Swing in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I need an advice how I should create my own layout. I know that I should create that from few another layouts but I want to know from which concretely. This is how i want to my layout look like:

[image: my Layout]

Can you help me ?

Comment: This is too broad a question - there are lots of ways you could do this. You should try to come up with at least 1 solution and post the problems you encounter with it here

Comment: I know that I can create this in few different ways but each layout is specializing in something as I know and i looking for the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do it something like this:

[image]

### As seen with extra width & height

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) That's what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make this layout with the [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

With that layout, you can, obviously make a grid and assign different amount of grid-tiles to your components.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but I would use one big BorderLayout with a horizontal FlowLayout inside NORTH and a vertical FlowLayout inside WEST. So the rest of the space would be taken by the list view.

Comment: `PAGE_START` & `LINE_START` are preferable to `NORTH` and `WEST` because they can adapt to localization (e.g. a GUI in Arabic would have the `LINE_START` on the right rather than the left of the GUI).

Comment: In FlowLayout can I create an empty field like at this image above?

Comment: I dont know if he wants it to swap sides. But in general thats good to know.

Comment: I would say with trailing alignment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html